# Flurry Agent causing a CalledFromWrongThreadException exception on Android 2.3.4

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, flurry

When I use the FlurryAgent on a 2.3.4 device I get the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FlurryAgent
        android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

In my code I made sure everything that is UI related is done on the UI thread.
I've tried disabling Flurry's exception capture via `FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(false)` but that did not help.

I find it hard to understand if Flurry is causing this exception or just reporting it, I tend to believe the former as when I comment out all Flurry calls, there is no exception/crash whatsoever.

I use the latest Flurry SDK - 3.2.1

Any ideas?

Comment: I faced the same problem while updating ListView from AsyncTask with Flurry 3.2.1

Comment: Im facing that too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with AsyncTask in the Android SDK previous to Jelly Bean that can cause this problem under certain conditions. Please, take a look at [Flurry's support page](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Guides/s/Publishers/Tips/Android), there is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! They explain the workaround in bullet #3.